# Scala tail recursion with actor using "receive"

Tags: scala, recursion, actor, tail

I have a problem trying to code a tail recursive `act()` for an actor in Scala:

```
case object JobRequest;
case object JobDone;

class Server(val nbJobs: Int, val nbClients: Int) extends Actor {
    @tailrec
    private def act(i: Int, j: Int) {
        if(j == 0) {
            println("Good bye.");
            exit();
        }

        receive {
            case JobRequest if(i == nbJobs) => sender ! JobDone; act(i, (j - 1));
            case JobRequest => sender ! i; act((i + 1), j);
        }
    }

    def act() = act(0, nbClients);
}
```

At compilation I get the following message:

```
error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method act: it contains a recursive call targetting a supertype
    receive {
    ^
```

The thing is I do want to receive messages, so what should I do?

---

EDIT:
I have found a first solution, the idea is to make the recursive call after the receive with something like that:

```
    @tailrec
    private def act(i: Int, j: Int) {
        if(j == 0) {
            println("Good bye.");
            exit();
        }

        receive {
            case JobRequest if(i == nbJobs) => sender ! JobDone; true;
            case JobRequest => sender ! i; false;
        } match {
            case true => act(i, (j - 1));
            case false => act((i + 1), j);
        }
    }
```

Is that the only way to do this?

Comment: You may want to use Akka actors, as Scala actors are deprecated. You won't have this issue there, because you need to implement `receive` (telling the actor how to handle messages) instead of `act`.